Problem with "self drawing svg with an image as background"
I do not succeed in coding a self drawing svg when it as an image as a background.
I can do it with a "simple" svg, thanks to GSAP and this kind of code:
const svg = document.querySelector("path");
  const length = svg.getTotalLength();
  svg.style.strokeDasharray = length;
  svg.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  gsap.to(svg, {
    strokeDashoffset: 0,
    duration: 5, 
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  });

But how can I do it with an svg with an image as a background, like:
  <svg id="svg1" class="display" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="mask">
                <path id="logo" d=""/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#mask)">
      <rect width="212" height="208" fill="#fff"></rect>
      <image id="bg3" class="bg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="assets/wavey.png" ></image>
      
      
  </g>
    </svg>

What is weird is that I can morph such an svg with an image for background into another svg with another image/background with morphSVG.
To be more specifi, i'm looking for the same kind of effect of self drawing svg one can see on site like https://crustac.fr/ with the self-drawing letter "C".
Thanks for your help!
Didier

You'd have to do the animation with SMIL or CSS animations because javascript does not run in image/ background contexts.

Please clarify, what you mean by "background-image": is it just in the background of your layout (while the svg is attached as a DOM element) or loaded as an external image resource via <img> or CSS background-image property? In the latter case, you won't be able to manipulate/animate your svg as commented by Robert Longson.

Thanks for your help. You're right, i misused the term background-image, which is a css term. The second excerpt of code I gave was more accurate, with the image wavey.jpg "fulfilling" the . And I would like a self-drawing animation of such an svg with an image, or a video, which fulfills the svg, just like in the website I mentionned.
